# Google Map Camera Location

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS application i'm using google maps SDK in order to get the current user location and it works fine now. But the problem is the camera position always aligned to right side. I want to align the position to left or centre. Can anyone please give me an idea...

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiHth.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if !didFindMyLocation {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as CLLocation
        viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
        viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true

        didFindMyLocation = true
    }
}
```

by Using

```
viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
```

it will centre to the current position.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. There was a small mistake in my code. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @user3480213 Please Mark it Correct. If it resolved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and i have been struggling with it for long time but i have found the solution and want to share with you to solve your problem as well.

Well, in our case the problem was the domain and the hosting provider. Basically the domain is at a different company and it points to the hosting servers. When i have changed the static response url to the hosting providers ip address /worldpay/processing/response it worked! Everybody has a different setup but i think the fact that our domain and hosting is at two different companies caused the problem.

Cheers